# How to control Sidekiq UI refreshing rate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have used Sidekiq for running asynchronous tasks in my rails application and i have used sidekiq::web(mount Sidekiq::Web => '/jobs' in routes.rb )to view the status of sidekiq jobs in UI. Once i opened the /jobs url in browser, it started refreshing for every 2 secs..

`Started GET "/jobs/dashboard/stats" for 192.168.1.1 at 2013-09-23 04:54:53 +0000
Started GET "/jobs/dashboard/stats" for 192.168.1.1 at 2013-09-23 04:54:55 +0000
Started GET "/jobs/dashboard/stats" for 192.168.1.1 at 2013-09-23 04:54:57 +0000
Started GET "/jobs/dashboard/stats" for 192.168.1.1 at 2013-09-23 04:55:01 +0000`

Is there any way to control this like increasing time of refresh or it should hit the server when i refersh the UI only.

Answer (score 1):

The dashboard performs regular requests to inform you about its status as close to real time as possible. This is usually the desired behaviour and only happens on the dashboard. As far as I know there is no way to configure this. The requests are performed via AJAX and I'm not sure if you can configure that with the normal Sidekiq Config or not.